# Why Varnish does not have any effect in sense of server response time with my nginx upstream and nodejs app?

Tags: nginx, varnish, node.js

I saw some php websites after putting Varnish in front of them responding in 0.2 seconds. Now I have:

1. Nginx upstream
2. Varnish in front of 1)
3. Two app servers with nodejs

My Varnish setup is standard:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
#some redirects from 80 to https hosts
}
```

Nginx listen on 443 and pass that to :80 varnish and then varnish pass that to nginx :8080 that has upstream of two servers. Nginx and two servers are in LAN (Microsoft azure)

Now my page response is from 0.7 to 1.5 seconds and that is just insane because homepage is using memcached for most of parts (even ajax calls that are under 0.1 seconds used some memcached stuff).

When running nodejs app on local i got response that is 0.3 - 0.4.

So as far as I can see Varnish does not:

1. Work (i got just in headers this: X-Varnish:98306)
   or
2. Cache

I can see stuff in Varnish log for every request but that does not help at all.

So, is there anyone who can hep me with this?

Comment: You should try using Pound for SSL instead of nginx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varnish, Nginx and even Apache can accelerate dynamic web sites by caching content. That's what they do. They cannot accelerate a slow site only by putting it in-front. They must cache content which usually needs time to get rendered on the server and deliver it as it would be a static web page.

The best way to make content cacheable is to set proper cache headers in your application. The application is the right place to do it as there is always different content in meaning of cacheablity:

- public visible content which can be cached
- public visible content which cannot be cached
- private content which can be cached for the right persons
- private content which cannot be cached

But sometimes web developer do not know about caching and so the application does not send proper caching headers. If this is the case you have to identify the different types of content and must configure Varnish, Nginx or Apache to do the right thing with the right type of content.

Actually I would check how complicated this is. You are already using Nginx for your web site. So for me it doesn't make sense to install additional software as Nginx can handle caching as well. But I would recommend to use Varnish if you like to use ESI or really complicated checks to differentiate the types of content.

**Next steps for you:**

Take a closer look into the caching headers (Cache-Control) of your application. I assume that you application doesn't send them so Varnish cannot cache and cannot accelerate your app.